# Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited android?

Tags: android-layout, android-manifest

In my application i have to do some changes in the manifest file. but i failed to do changes the manifest file. Please help me how do i change the manifest file in android?

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.reloadapp.reload"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/re"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.SplashActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".fragments.SplashActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.MainActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.DateofBirth_Activity"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.Webviewfreecredits"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.PaymentFailure"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.Payment_Success"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.Pic"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.Resetpassword_Activtiy"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.Login_Activity"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.Facebookwebview"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.Register_Activtiy"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.ForgotPassword_Activity"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.Payment_Actiivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.Atmdebitwebview"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.Netbanking_Webview"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

i want to remove the android:icon in every activity and save. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the logo file name have any numbers, remove it and rename it by letters only